# Composer Hanging on Installing dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php

After reading others with this question, most said to be patient.
It's been running for roughly 15 hours now and still nothing.
I've got it on the AWS EC2 Micro, which I know the ram is low but I added a 512mb swap.
Both the memory and cpu sit around 90%.

Is it safe to say that it's not going to finish or will it eventually do something? Is there anyway to log this process to see what it's doing?

Comment: Tried running it with the [`--verbose` flag](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options)?

Comment: Nope, I'd hate to cancel it if it may be finishing soon :\, what do you think?

Comment: I think 15 hours is far too long to wait

Comment: Okay, I'm rerunning it with that command

Comment: This is the exact command I ran: php composer.phar install --dev --verbose --profile
After ~5 minutes I still haven't seen anything new from before.

Comment: What version of  composer, and what is in your  composer.json file? The above command doesn't help much - it's not reproducible. Also note you can bump up verbosity - I.e. `-vvv`. Please add any new info _to the question_.

Comment: "but I added a 512mb swap" Hello large EC2 fees! Adding a swap to a micro instance is a bad idea, as you pay per IO request. It's only $0.10 per million requests but it can add up.

Comment: @Danack Thanks for this, AWS pricing is so obscure, seems I only ran up a million though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Composer is supposed to finish a reasonably sized install job within seconds. It might probably need some minutes to finish if there is a really huge amount of packages to be installed (by huge I mean more than I experienced yet, i.e. probably more than 100 packages).

The process uses an unusual amount of RAM compared with other PHP scripts, i.e. hundreds of megabytes is not uncommon.

I'd advise to not run Composer on such a badly equipped machine. Adding swap space will not help in any way, it will just make the machine read and write to disk heavily, delaying the whole process by orders of magnitudes (like 100 or 1000 times slower). You should run the install step on your development machine, and then copy everything to the Amazon instance.

How long does it run on your local machine?

Comment: Good idea, I'll just transfer it over, it runs fine locally.

Comment: @Stephen L did it help you?